# unable to generate log file using log4j

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, log4j

I am using tomcat 6 with eclipse Luna (Along with axis2 for webservices). I have imported the required log4j jar file(log4j-1.2.17.jar) and inserted the following line in the class also

```
static org.apache.log4j.Logger log = Logger.getLogger(WS.class);
```

Here is the properties file:

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
# Set the name of the file
log4j.appender.FILE.File=log.txt

# Set the immediate flush to true (default)
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true

# Set the threshold to debug mode
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug

# Set the append to false, overwrite
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern= %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %c %p %t %m%n%n
```

The properties file is in the src folder and jar file is in the build path of eclipse. I tried all different ways but unable to generate log file.

Comment: Have you checked the directory where log4jProperties file is present , included in ClassPath ??

Comment: @NeerajJain It is in src folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the properties file in `resources` folder not `src` folder.

I just tested your properties file and it's ok. And when I put it in `src` folder, it did not work.

Comment: I have placed the properties file in resource folder also but still its not workng

Comment: Did you mark your resources file as ```Resources```? In IDEA it's in File--Project Structure--Modules--Sources

Comment: How do I mark it as resources in eclipse? I have never heard of it

Comment: Maybe it's not neccessary in eclipse. Have you tried a xml properties file?

Comment: Yes just now I tried with XML. With XML file its not even generating console output

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me before.
It might be the issue of write privilege.
Do you try to write to stdout or socket instead of file?
If that works, then try to redirect your file output to a tmp directory.

Comment: Ok I will try it and see

Comment: Its not writing to stdout